# JS script get deactivated every time a new PatchOn is applied

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am new to development of dynamic CRM 365. So I have this issue which I will explain:

- I added to the CRM solution a JS script and it gave some error to the production environment after exporting this from main development environment as managed. So someone deactivated the script.
- Then after solving the problem, the PatchOn was applied again but it did not by default activated the script in production environment. Even, every time a new PatchOn is applied, the script gets deactivated and it has to be manually activated again.
  In main development environment, the solutions/PatchOns are kept as unmanaged. From there those are exported as managed to prod environment.
  So question is, what can be the possible reason for the script to get deactivated each time?

Comment: Does anyone have any overview?

Comment: I believe this is basically due to your Patch which is unmanaged and unmanaged deployment does not affect, activation/deactivation of Js. If you deploy managed I believe this will have activate Js (if your Js is active in develop system)

Comment: The managed solution contains PatOn with activated script and is deployed to production environment but it does not yet activate the script unless it is manually activated. I am looking for a fix how can this be always activated and every time when any new PatchOn is deployed, this will not be deactivated. @AnkUser